# Whenever try to debug .NET Core Project in Visual Studio, face issue "A socket operation was attempted to unreachable network"

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, debugging

[image]

I am working on two different projects Project A and Project B in Visual Studio. Both are hosted on AWS and I usually use AWS keys to access Mysql and other features (Amazon Dynamo DB and S3 )using access keys that I had entered in Visual Studio AWS Explorer. I entered AWS Keys correctly but didn't know the issue.

1. Project A always show this error whenever I click on Debug button although there is no error in the code and if I click on continue  button for multiple times, then it works. I had verified that I had entered AWS access credentials correctly as well as connected to AWS VPN
2. However Project B does not show any kind of error although it is on AWS .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4kBs.png)

Comment: Post your code and *full* error message or exceptions as text in the question itself. You can copy an exception's full text if you click on `Copy Details` in the exception popup. The full exception contains the location where the error occured, any inner exceptions and a stack trace of the function calls that led to it.

Comment: The error is not there in any code but while clicking on the debug button.

Comment: I'd have to repeat the same comment. Post the full exception details *as text*. Post the steps to reproduce it. Otherwise the question will be closed due to the lack of information.

Comment: The error message itself tells you the application can't connect to whatever server it's trying to reach. This isn't about keys, this is a networking error. You may be trying to connect to an internal IP from outside a network. Or may be blocked by a company firewall. Or trying to access a machine on a private network you have no access to.

Comment: `while clicking on the debug button.` which starts your application and any code that tries to connect to AWS. It may not be your code but a plugin. The error says you can't even access whatever you try to connect to.

Comment: *Post the error text!* Not images. That will tell you what the issue is. At the very least it will tell you more than "can't connect"

Comment: I had updated the problem statement as well as I had shared the details of the error message as the image.

Comment: No you didn't. There's no error text. Only another link to something, not even another image. Post the error text. Click on `Copy Details` and post that text. VS is making it far easier to copy the exception text than taking screenshots

Comment: In any case this is a network error. Either the VPN required by the second project is different, the VPN is down, or there's a problem with your AWS assets (services? VMs?). Only AWS support can solve this. Or perhaps you have an unstable line and the connection fails shortly after connection. Or the connection times out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.